# Does the RSS protocol support categories?

Tags: rss

I've never seen a feed reader that supports unsubscribing from posts with a particular category. This seems like such a logical feature for RSS users (who tend to be power users), that I've started to wonder if this is due to a limitation of the protocol. Does the RSS protocol have an official feature to support categories? Alternatively, is there an unofficial extension that has this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) defines category tags for both [items](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) and [channels](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#optionalChannelElements), but it depends on the publisher how well they categorize their content.